# Symfony User entity (PhpStorm warning)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpstorm

I have Symfony entity with auto-generated setUser() method:

```php
    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
```

In controller I use built-in `getUser()` method, which returns `UserInterface` object. And when I pass that `UserInterface` object to `setUser()` method, PhpStorm complains that:

```
Expected parameter of type '\App\Entity\User', 'object|\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface' provided
```

I'd like to write code without such PhpStorm warnings. Should I create new User() to pass it to setUser() method or just ignore that?

Comment: you can annotate objects that functions return like `/** @var $user User */ $user = $this->getUser();` (with linebreak). this will tell static analysis that the getUser method actually returns a User in this case.

Comment: I think you are missing to add UserInterface class in an entity User(User implements UserInterface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: (thanks to Jakumi comment)

```php
public function __invoke() {
    /** @var $user App\Entity\User */
    $user = $this->getUser();
    
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity->setUser($user);
    
    //...
}
```